# why can't write the printable ascii into file in R?

Tags: r

From  32 to 255 in decimal number ,the ascii is printable character,i want to write them into the file `c:/asciitest`.

```
for(i in 32:255){
    rawToChar(as.raw(i))->x;
    cat("the ",i," ",x,"\n");
    #you can try in R console with `cat("the ",i," ,x,"\n");`
    }
```

why i get only part of them?the line which contain  `?` character are:
32,34,127,and form 129  to  255,how can i make them readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[those and more between 32 and 127 are non-printable](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/idp/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html):

- 32: SPACE
- 34: non-printable
- 127: DEL

from 128 to 255 you introduce a second byte to describe the character. this conflicts with your character encoding setting. only the ANSI part from 0 to 127 is compatible with UTF-N.

Additionally you might have to adjust the fileEncoding-attribute when writing to a file or options(encoding="...") for your console and default encoding. otherwise any character encoded longer than a single byte (ANSI) might be interpreted incorrectly.